# Find, Copy & Paste Values under Multiple Columns

Tags: vba, excel

Below code is for copying values under "Apple" Column in sheet1 to "AppleNew" Column in sheet2. (Thanks to Tim)

But If I have multiple columns (Orange, Banana etc) is there way to write more simpler code that sort of go through the loop instead of having to copy and paste code for the each columns?

```
Dim rng as range, rngCopy as range, rng2 as range

set rng = Sheet1.Rows(3).Find(What:="Apple", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

if not rng is nothing then

    set rngCopy = Sheet1.range(rng.offset(1,0), _
                               Sheet1.cells(rows.count,rng.column).end(xlUp))

    set rng2 = Sheet2.Rows(1).Find(What:="AppleNew", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                   LookAt:=xlWhole)

    if not rng2 is nothing then rngCopy.copy rng2.offset(1,0)

end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub Tester()

    DoColumnCopy "Apple", "AppleNew"
    DoColumnCopy "Apple2", "Orange"

end sub

sub Tester2()
   dim i, arrFrom, arrTo

   arrFrom = Array("Apple","Apple2") 'source cols
   arrTo=Array("AppleNew","Orange")  'destination cols

   for i=lbound(arrFrom) to ubound(arrFrom)
       DoColumnCopy Cstr(arrFrom(i)), Cstr(arrTo(i)) 'EDIT: pass as strings
   next i
end sub




Sub DoColumnCopy(FromColName as string, ToColName as string)

    Dim rng as range, rngCopy as range, rng2 as range

    set rng = Sheet1.Rows(3).Find(What:=FromColName , LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlWhole)

    if not rng is nothing then

        set rngCopy = Sheet1.range(rng.offset(1,0), _
                        Sheet1.cells(rows.count,rng.column).end(xlUp))

        set rng2 = Sheet2.Rows(1).Find(What:=ToColName , LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                   LookAt:=xlWhole)

        if not rng2 is nothing then rngCopy.copy rng2.offset(1,0)

    end if

end sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim!, so do I need to run this 3 separate subs?
Because I am trying to make a button and assign a macro, so I would need 3 buttons?

Comment: I get a Compile error: ByRef Argument type mismatch on the line   
`DoColumnCopy arrFrom(i), arrTo(i)`

Comment: `Tester` and `Tester2` are just examples of how to call `DoColumnCopy` (which you'd have to add to your module).  I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, so you'll have to work that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim varColName As Variant

For Each varColName In Array("Orange", "Banana", "Pear")

    'Your code goes here
    'In your code, replace "Apple" with varColName
    'In your code, replace "AppleNew" with varColName & "New"

Next varColName
```

Comment: I am bit confused. Do I just copy my codes under this varColName? sorry for being lost as I am fairly new to VBA, though I would appreciate it if you elaborate more. Thank you!

Comment: So `Find(What:=varColName & New, LookIn:=xlValues,                                   LookAt:=xlWhole)` ?

Comment: Put your code where it says `'Your code goes here` and then in your code, make the replacements as shown.  So instead of `.Find(What:="Apple",` it would be `.Find(What:=varColName,` and instead of `.Find(What:="AppleNew",` it would be `.Find(What:=varColName & "New",`

Comment: I have quick additional question if you don't mind,
If my sheet2 column names aren't always `varColName & "New"` is there way to put that in a array as something like varColName2?  
Thank you so much in advance